# Using mutate with multiple functions

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, across

I am trying to provide two functions inside the **mutate(across(where(is.factor)))** to order the factor levels and drop unused levels. The code appears not to be working as expected. Where might have gone wrong?

```
#---- Libraries ----

library(tidyverse)

#---- Data ----

set.seed(2021)

df <- tibble(
  a1 = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  a2 = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  gender = gl(2, 15, labels = c("Males", "Females")),
  b2 = gl(3, 10, labels = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary", "Unknown")),
  c1 = gl(3, 10, labels = c("15-19", "20-24", "25-30", "30-35")),
  outcome = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  weight = runif(30, 1, 12)
)

#---- Problem ----

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), list(fct_infreq, fct_drop)))

levels(df$b2)

# The unused levels not dropped
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are actually mutating two new columns here, so you will see in your resulting dataframe that there are two columns `b2_1` and `b2_2`, each corresponding to applying the two functions.

If you run `levels(df$b2_2)` you'll see your desired output.

If your aim is to first drop and then reorder then you need to run consecutive mutates:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), fct_drop)) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), fct_infreq))
```

or run nested functions in your mutate

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~fct_infreq(fct_drop(.x))))
```

Comment: So then it means we are unable to use more than one function in mutate?